# Question about reflexive verbs & adjectives and tense

Tags: грамматика

Mistaken (adj) = ошибочный

Can someone **PLEASE** explain how the endings in the following came about? They don't seem to be following the normal rules for adjectives and conjugation that I've studied.

```
I am mistaken = я ошибаюсь;
I was mistaken = я ошибался;
He is mistaken = он ошибается;
He was mistaken = он ошибся;
She is mistaken = она ошибается;
She was mistaken = она ошиблась;
You are mistaken = вы ошиблись;
You were mistaken = Вы ошиблись;
They are mistaken = они ошибаются;
They were mistaken = они ошиблись;
```

Comment: "you are mistaken = вы ошиблись;" - no, it is "вы ошибаетесь".

Comment: Those are not endings of an adjective in your table. Do you know reflexive verbs?

Comment: You use two different verbs: "ошибаться" and "ошибиться"

Answer (score 5):

It's from verb *ошибаться*. Adjective *ошибочный* is used to describe something, not someone.
For example

> Он ошибается - He is mistaken
>
> Ошибочное мнение - Mistaken opinion

But be aware that you can translate 'mistaken' as *неправильно понятый* (misunderstood).

Answer (score 0):

Where the endings had come from?

Some blurring arise because you are blending two verbs (blending endings) that being structurally parallel in its aspect pair `ошибаться и ошибиться`.

Open in parallel [ошибаться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)|[ошибиться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) and take a look at its tables. 90% of native speakers are at all certain that the two verbs is blending into the one. So, at 90% you have a right ))

---

and incidentally,

```
Я ушибла лоб.                       I have hurt my forehead. (I said: she)
Она ушиблась прямо о [...] .        She bumped straight into a [...].
Набила шишку на голове.             Get a bump on her head. (and paint the bump with iodine)
Оставив на ee голове хорошенькую шишку.       Giving her head a nasty bump.
Она сделала много ошибок.           She has made many errors.
Да, я ошиблась.                     Yes, I am mistaken. / I am wrong. (I said: she)
Да, я набила шишек в этой теме (ошиблась).  — an idiom
Нет, это ошибочное мнение.          No, It is a mistaken opinion.
```

Idiom, usage with a context: [набить шишек = have made errors](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%E1%E8%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=6&lex2=%F8%E8%F8%EA%E0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&lang=en)